# Javascript match error - Invalid quantifier

Tags: jquery

i get an strange error "invalid quantifer" ... can somebody help me please?

**html**

```
<input type="text" value="5+5" id="test"/>
```

**JS**

```
  ups = {};
  ups['2'] = new Array();
  ups['2']['cmd'] = '#(\-|\+|\*|\/|)[0-9](,|[0-9]|)(\-|\+|\*|\/)[0-9]#gi';     

  var inp_val = $('#test').val();
  if (inp_val.match(ups['2']['cmd']))
  {
     $('body').append('<br />OK');                 
  }
```

http://www.jsfiddle.net/V9Euk/639/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Javascript, Regular expressions should be written as

```
var re = /thepatterns/mod;
```

i.e.

```
  ups = {};
  ups['2'] = new Array();
  ups['2']['cmd'] = /(\-|\+|\*|\/|)[0-9](,|[0-9]|)(\-|\+|\*|\/)[0-9]/gi;
```

moreover, it can be simplified as

```
  ups = {2: {cmd: /([-+*\/])\d([,\d]?)([-+*\/])\d/g }};
```

---

The reason for the invalid quantifier is that, unlike PHP, a `\` followed by an unrecognized character will result in that character without the `\`:

- Javascript `'\p\q' == 'pq'`
- PHP `'\p\q' == '\\p\\q'`

Therefore, your  string  will be interpreted as

```
'#(-|+|*|/|)[0-9](,|[0-9]|)(-|+|*|/)[0-9]#gi'
```

which is an invalid regex since the `+` (a quantifier) is not preceded by any patterns.